# Default template arguments for the C++11 'using' type alias

Tags: templates, c++11, using

I want to alias a type so that it can be given a template argument if necessary.

```
template<typename T, unsigned d>
struct value
{
    T a[d];
};

template<typename T=float>
using val=value<T, 2>;

int main()
{
    val v;      //should now be equal to val<float> v;
    val<int> w; //should also be valid.
    return 0;
}
```

G++ does not approve for some reason:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:12:13: error: missing template arguments before ‘v’
         val v;      //should now be equal to val<float> v;
             ^
test.cpp:12:13: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘v’
```

Do default template arguments not work with 'using'?
If so, why does it not say so on the line the default argument is specified on?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Introduction

Having default values for *template-parameters* in a *alias-template* **is** legal, but you cannot leave out `<`, and `>`, when you are later using said alias.

```cpp
template<class T = float>
using val = value<T, 2>;

val<>    v; // legal, decltype(v) => value<float, 2>
val<int> w; // legal, decltype(w) => value<int,   2>
```

---

#### What does the Standard say? ([n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf))

> `14.5.7p1` **Alias templates** `[temp.alias]`
>
> > A *template-declaration* in which the *declaration* is an *alias-declaration* (Clause 7) declares the *identifier* to be a *alias-template*. An alias template is a name for a family of types. The name of the alias template is a *template-name*.

The above states that the name introduced by a *template-alias* is a *template-name*, and a *template-name* must be followed by a *template-argument-list*.

> `14.2p1` **Names of template specialization** `[temp.names]`
>
> > ```
> > simple-template-id:
> >   template-name < template-argument-list_opt >
> >
> > template-name:
> >   identifier
> > ```

<sup>**Note**: Notice how the two `<>` are not optional when referring to a *simple-template-id*, and that a *template-name* by itself is merely an identifier, not a type.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

You can use only function templates without `<>`. For classes empty list of template parameters is necessary:

```
    val<> v;    //should now be equal to val<float> v;
```